# Public and Private Keys - Clients/Server Communication

Tags: sockets, encryption, rsa, private-key, public-key

So Currently, I am trying to understand public/private keys with servers and clients work.

Overall, I am trying to set up a server (Socket Stream) storing all messages which will show up encrypted on the server side.

When a user connects through entering the port and its username, through the client application, any message intended for this user will show while the messages which arent will stay encrypted. These messages will all be sent to the client side from the server which is storing it currently.

So lets say Alice wants to messages Pami secretly, Pami's public key will be used to encrypt the message while alice's private key will be used for the signature.

For this, will encryption be done on the server side and decryption on the client side or does both occur on the same side?

Comment: It's not end-to-end encryption anymore once you sent the private key from the client to the server and it's not transport encryption if the server's private key has been exposed to the client.

Comment: Does client hold its own private key and server only access to public key. This means server will encrypt messages with the users public key who the message is intended for?

Comment: Encryption is done by the sender, and decryption is done by the receiver. Both server and client can both send and receive. Your question doesn't make sense as stated.

Comment: Data is sent to the server by client - Does this client encrypt. Data is also sent back to clients who connect to the server which is decrypted if the user has the right priv key - The client here does the decryption. Or is decryption and encryption both done on the client side?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. When you want to offer end-to-end encryption, the client encrypts and decrypts the message and the server cannot read any clients private key or cleartext message at any point.

Comment: +1 "it depends on what you want to do." Maybe you could learn how encryption works, by doing some experiments with encryption without sockets, and then you'll learn some more about encryption and have an idea of how this works.

Comment: Encryption is very easy. Trust is very difficult. How does Alice retrieve Pami's public key? How does Alice know the public key is really from Pami? It might be forged by the server. You can only trust a key if Alice talks directly to Pami, without a server. That's a problem in the internet, because you never have a direct communication. Several internet providers are between them, several transparent and non-transparent gateways. Do you know whatsapp? If you want to verify someone's key, you need to check the QR code analog from the other persons device, without internet.

Comment: Would there ever be an instance when a Server would hold public keys in order to encrypt data. This would lead to the data being vulnerable when transferring to the server or am I wrong in this instance?